# SQLite errors on null object reference

Tags: sqlite, java, android

I have validated and re-verified the data going into and out of this procedure but still the SQLite database errors on null object reference.

```
    // process for updating the active flag for the current user
public void updateActiveFlag(boolean _active, String _uid){
    int val = (_active) ? 1 : 0;

    //1.get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //2.create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("active", val); //update active flag

    //3.updating row
    db.update(TABLE_NAME,values,COLUMN_ACTIVE + "='" + _uid + "'",null);

    //4.close
    db.close();
}
```

The only thing that works is for me to wipe the AVD and change the database version. This work-around does not help my project. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going on? I am almost certain that this procedure is correctly written but I need another set of eyes.

Here is the Error Log

> 2019-10-29 14:49:28.755 8498-8498/com.bab_c.picksandbets W/System.err:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
>   android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int,
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory,
>   android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
>   2019-10-29 14:49:28.755 8498-8498/com.bab_c.picksandbets W/System.err:
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
>   2019-10-29 14:49:28.755 8498-8498/com.bab_c.picksandbets W/System.err:
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>   2019-10-29 14:49:28.755 8498-8498/com.bab_c.picksandbets W/System.err:
>   at
>   **com.bab_c.picksandbets.Controller.DatabaseHelper.updateActiveFlag(DatabaseHelper.java:215)**
>   2019-10-29 14:49:28.755 8498-8498/com.bab_c.picksandbets W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.bab_c.picksandbets.Controller.UUIDData.matchUserStatus(UUIDData.java:452) 2019-10-29 14:49:28.755 8498-8498/com.bab_c.picksandbets W/System.err:
>   at com.bab_c.picksandbets.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)

Comment: share your error logs.

Comment: Identify the exact line at which the error occurs.  There is no reason to make us guess and/or analyze the code just to figure out error details when you have access and can get that information yourself.

Comment: The second line of your stack trace seems to be truncated. The information needed to figure out the problem is on this line and possibly following lines that you missed.